# How to make a DLL in VB 6.0

Tags: dll, vb6

How would I make a DLL in VB 6.0?

Comment: Have you searched in Google?  I'd be surprised that there are no pages describing this.

Comment: What sort of DLL do you want to create? One containing COM objects, exporting "C" style functions, or just containing resources?

Comment: People have downvoted this question without leaving any comments, which I think is a bit rude. I didn't downvote the question myself. I'm guessing it's because (i) you haven't provided much context - what do you need your DLL to do and what's the client? and also (ii) because you said "please write steps please please" which people dislike.

Comment: Just not enough info to even try to give an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean an ActiveX DLL (in which case this question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477265/com-dll-in-vb6)).

Just work through the step-by-step guide from the VB6 user guide [Creating An ActiveX DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229332(v=VS.60).aspx). It's pretty good. It goes through creating the project, building the DLL, and making a client project, and then it explains some underlying concepts and gotchas.

If you mean a standard DLL check out the free tool [vbAdvance](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google revealed [these](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2005/04/26/create_dll.html?page=3) instructions

Answer (score 0):

Here's an FAQ I wrote on the subject a few years ago: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5940

@ John Sibly: I don't think the OP was looking for how to create a standard (non-COM) DLL, but of course I could be wrong.  The OP was pretty vague, after all.  :)