# Can not add reference a COM in COM client?

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop

A COM server is create and I registerd that.

When I am trying to add that COM server in a COM Client, I was not able to add, and following error is comming.

> " A reference to 'COMTest' could not
>   be added
>
> The ActiveX type Library
>   'c\user\~\Debug\COMTest.tlb' was
>   exported from a .NET assembly and can
>   not added as a reference.
>
> Add a reference to .NET instead "

can anybody tell me What is the mistake. I register the COM in both way, from VS also and also tried with command prompt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a "why on Earth would you do that" message.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, select the DLL, not the TLB.  So you'll use the .NET class(es) directly instead of going through the COM interop twice.

Comment: IMO it's a **"why on earth doesn't this work"** situation. The .NET assembly can be used as COM Server (*"It's simple! Just add the ComVvisible attribute!"*), .NET apps can be COM clients (*"nwe and improved with the latest update"*).  It should be a warning, not a full-stop. ----- Use case: I am replacing a native COM component with a .NET one, but the .NET client needs to remain compatible with both.

Comment: .. That is true I can go for browse. But I am learning COM, and I am not able to understand the error!! I am registering the DLL as well as the tlb.... Even I gave snk key also.

@peterchen....  ComVisible(true), I tried both, can explain me error.

Comment: You should write the client code in a different language.  Javascript, VBScript, VB6, something like that.  Late binding is supported, VB.NET is a good language for that.  Or the *dynamic* keyword in C# 4.

Comment: @peterchen Another use case: the COM assembly is 32-bit and the referencing assembly is 64-bit.  I *cannot* add a reference to it as a .NET assembly, because though that will succeed, it will not run.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you referring .tlb. you should refer .dll,

And after registering it with regsvr32,You just need to find that dll in .net add reference in com tab. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310681/how-do-i-call-a-visual-basic-6-0-method-in-c/4561990#4561990) for more.