# How can I test a COM interface implemented in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, com

I have written a COM interface in C#. I then tried to write a simple application that references it so that I can test the COM interface, however Visual Studio does not allow COM interfaces to be referenced if they have been written in C#.

Is there any way to get around this? If not, which language is likely to be the easiest for me to accomplish my task?

Comment: How about the Excel VBA editor? You can add it as a reference there, and test out the interface.

Comment: _Visual Studio does not allow COM interfaces to be referenced if they have been written in C#._ Really? Perhaps you did not register the type library correctly? In that case you will not be able to test your COM object no matter which tool you decide to use.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: It *might* be possible to work around it, but by default it doesn't seem to be possible out of the box. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614625/can-not-add-reference-a-com-in-com-client

Comment: I second Excel VBA.  It's common, fast, and very straightforward.  If you're struggling to come up with a plan to do this then Excel is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the Excel VBA editor for this.

Open Excel, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to invoke the VBA editor.

Create a new module, go to Tools -> References, find your COM object in the list, and check the box.

You should then be able to create an object, and test your interface is working.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, even though I went down the VB6 route in the end!