# Get rid of the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, com

We have an old application which can be extended only by using COM exposed assemblies. There is now way to work with it without the GAC. The extension we want to provide is an existing .NET component. We want to provide the extension without putting all required references in the GAC as well. I came up with a solution to do this.

I'll host a WCF service in a windows service and use a named pipe endpoint. This endpoint will be consumed by the COM component. This way the COM component is only forwarding call's and I don't need any dependant assemblies in the GAC.

Two questions about this setup:
1. Are there better ways to do what I want?
2. How can I keep the COM component as small as possible? (it's just a forwarding point)

Comment: .NET components can exist w/o putting them in the GAC (regasm /codebase)

Comment: Didn't know that. Will the assembly be at a specific folder which I can specify? Will it search in that directory for required reference assemblies?

Comment: It will be referenced where it was regasm'd. Same for referenced assemblies, you can regasm /codebase them as well.

Comment: My GAC/COM knowledge is very limited and I can't get it to work. I created three .net assemblies. A client console (1), using COMComponent library (2) which references COMComponentReference library (3). I registered the COMComponent with regasm. How do I reference this from the client console? It's not in the GAC.

Comment: When you use RegAsm, it can/will create a COM Type Library (.TLB file). You can reference that TLB.

Comment: No I can't, it will complain that it is a tlb from a CLR assembly and I should directly reference the assembly itself.

Comment: oh ok, yes, but your whole story is not clear. Why would you do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614625/can-not-add-reference-a-com-in-com-client

Comment: I want to test if I can call the COM component from another application. I already found the way to do that, so thanks for all your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56411/discussion-between-tom-kuijsten-and-simon-mourier).