# Blank method in the type library C#

Tags: c#, com, tlbimp

I have an .exe assembly with a class like

```
[Guid("2D9EBA5F-7E4A-418B-B151-4E703AEDF396")]
public interface MyInterface
{
   int MyMethod();
}
[GuidAttribute("D26278EA-A7D0-4580-A48F-353D1E455E50"),
ProgIdAttribute("My_prog"), ComVisible(true), Serializable]
public class MyInterface: MyClass
{
   public int MyMethod()
   {
     return 1;
   }
}
```

I register it like

```
regasm 1.exe /tlb 1.tlb
```

I have two questions:

1) I am opening it with an object explorer, "COM" tab. I can see my assembly, I can see an object there, but I can't see any methods in this class. What's wrong?

2) I am trying to reference it from the second project, Add reference -> COM (VS2010).
I get the error:

> " A reference to 'assemblyname' could not be added.
>
> The ActiveX type Library 'path\1.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and can not added as a reference.
>
> Add a reference to .NET instead "

Yes, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614625/can-not-add-reference-a-com-in-com-client) question. But I don't want to make a direct reference to the assembly, I want to access it through COM! What should I do to make the assembly referenceable through COM?

Comment: Why is your interface not ComVisible?

Comment: @Paul-Jan With ComVisible interface I still can't see methods in class, so it doesn't change anything.

Comment: There are several bizarre typos in the question, hard to assume anything.  But no, Visual Studio insists that you always use an normal .NET assembly reference instead of a COM reference for .NET assemblies.  Using COM makes no sense.

Comment: Like Hans says, why is you Interface the same name as the class? I would have thought that causes a compile error.