# How to dynamically load VB 6.0 dll in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, vb6, interop

I have a VB 6.0 dll which has a method like below:

```
Public Function PrintDemo() As Integer
PrintDemo = 10
End Function
```

The dll is registered on my machine. I need to load this dll dynamically into C#. Below is the way I tried in C#:

```
Type obj = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Project1.Class1");
object ins = Activator.CreateInstance(obj);

var method1 = obj.InvokeMember("PrintDemo", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);
Console.WriteLine(method1);
```

The dll is getting loaded successfully but I am unable to invoke it.

Could someone help me on this ?

Comment: Your never passing the instance (ins) into the invoke member. That could be one problem

Comment: For what you are trying to do, maybe this approach is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310681/how-do-i-call-a-visual-basic-6-0-method-in-c

Comment: @drew_w but then it wouldn't be dynamic, and wouldn't you be forced to register the ActiveX DLL on all computers that should run it, and every time you change something?

Comment: You are correct - was just looking into this and figured I would mention the ActiveX route as a possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change

```
obj.InvokeMember("PrintDemo", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);

// To...
obj.InvokeMember("PrintDemo", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ins, null);
```

I believe you should be sending the instance 'ins' as target and not the Type.
Otherwise there would be no reason to create an instance.

It's a really long time since I've worked with reflection...