# How to wrap VB code and C++ code and espose it as 3 COM interfaces to 3rd party?

Tags: c++, com, vb6

I am not familiar with VB code (C++ programmer), but now I need to provide a COM interface to 3rd party but the existing functionality is in some ancient VB code.

So my question is is it possible to wrap those up to inside a COM interface? If so how to do it?

I basically need to provide 3 wrapper COM interfaces to a 3rd party, one from old VB code, the other two from old C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the code into classes in an ActiveX DLL project. You can then create the public classes and call the methods you need.

Comment: +1. AFAIK it is *much* easier to expose classes through COM in VB6 than in C++.

Comment: Well, the C++ code will have to be exposed by a C++ library which should be a seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is *much* easier to expose classes through COM in VB6 than in C++.

You need to create an ActiveX DLL, like Deanna says. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477265/com-dll-in-vb6) for some detailed step-by-step guides and links to the documentation.

Comment: Mark,sorry I have added more to the question as I need some code from C++ as well.